# IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0 CE How do I solve the “Waiting for platform auth service” error message

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, ibm-cloud-private

Need assistance with ICP install.I have encountered the following error during installation IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0 on Ubuntu server. I followed the official installation guide step by step,but got the error message below.Error happened at Ubuntu Server and Redhat server both single node or multiple node. Did I missing any step or wrong configuration.Please give some support on this installation issue.Thanks!

Official installation guide link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/installing.html

1.Server info:Ubuntu 16.04, 4Core CPU,16G Memory,150G Disk,Docker version 17.10.0-ce 
2.Hosts file(show single node situation,use * to hide credential info): [master] 9.111.*.* [worker] 9.111.*.* [proxy] 9.111.*.* 3.config.yaml(show single node situation change): 
ansible_user: root 
ansible_ssh_pass: ***** 
ansible_ssh_common_args: "-oPubkeyAuthentication=no" 
4.Other step: 
config /etc/hosts file add 9.111.*. hostname 
Set vm.max_map_count to 262144 
sudo apt install python 
disable SELinux setenforce 0 
sudo apt-get install python-pip

Error message: TASK [addon : Waiting for platform auth service] ************************************************************************************ FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (50 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (49 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (48 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (47 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (46 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (45 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (44 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (43 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (42 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (41 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (40 retries left). FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: addon : Waiting for platform auth service (39 retries left).

Comment: This issue have been solved by using a 8Core,16G Memory Server.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not having 127.0.0.1 as DNS configured (also no dnsmasq on your host). It will be mirrored to the nodes which result in non working DNS resolution inside the containers. If you have the need to use dnsmasq then install it outside your environment and point to it in /etc/resolv.conf from your installation environment.